# Express: Why I cannot access session variable in one method while I can access it in another?

Tags: node.js, express, node-modules, express-session

I am using the `googleapis` dependency for getting user details using the google+ api. I store the access_token in the session when there is a redirect from google`(app.get(/auth/google/callback))`. But when I try to access it at the route `(/details)` I can't achieve it. 
The code for both routes is --

For google redirect route--

```js
app.get('/auth/google/callback', (req, res) => {
    let code = req.query.code;
    var session = req.session;
    oauthClient.getToken(code, (err, token) => {
        if(!err){
            //res.json(token)
            session['token'] = token;
            oauthClient.credentials = token;
            console.log('session ', req.session.token.access_token); // <------------ is accessible
            res.redirect('/details');
        }
        else{
            res.json({
                Error: 'Authorization error',
            });
        }
    });

})
```

For details route--

```js
app.get('/details', (req, res, next) => {
    console.log(req.session.token.access_token); // <-------------cannot access req.session.token.access_token
    plus.people.get({
        userId: 'me',
        auth: oauthClient
    }, (err, userInfo) => {
        if(err){
            console.log("Error while fetching user info");
        }
        else{
            res.json(userInfo);   
        }
    });
});
```

This is the error--

```sh
TypeError: Cannot read property 'access_token' of undefined
    at app.get (C:\Users\shahaji.shinde\Desktop\practice\google-signin\app.js:49:35)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\Users\shahaji.shinde\Desktop\practice\google-signin\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
    at next (C:\Users\shahaji.shinde\Desktop\practice\google-signin\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:137:13)
    at Route.dispatch (C:\Users\shahaji.shinde\Desktop\practice\google-signin\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:112:3)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\Users\shahaji.shinde\Desktop\practice\google-signin\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
    at C:\Users\shahaji.shinde\Desktop\practice\google-signin\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:281:22
    at Function.process_params (C:\Users\shahaji.shinde\Desktop\practice\google-signin\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:335:12)
    at next (C:\Users\shahaji.shinde\Desktop\practice\google-signin\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:275:10)
    at Immediate._onImmediate (C:\Users\shahaji.shinde\Desktop\practice\google-signin\node_modules\express-session\index.js:489:7)
    at runCallback (timers.js:793:20)
```

The whole app.js--

```js
const express = require('express');
const session = require('express-session');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const oauthClient = require('./oauthclient');
const google = require('googleapis');
const plus = google.plus('v1');
const config = require('./config');
const port  = 3000;
const app = express();

app.use(bodyParser.json());

//Session 
app.use(session({
    secret: config.session.secret,
    resave: true,
    saveUninitialized: true 
}));

app.get('/auth/google/callback', (req, res) => {
    let code = req.query.code;
    var session = req.session;
    oauthClient.getToken(code, (err, token) => {
        if(!err){
            //res.json(token)
            session['token'] = token;
            oauthClient.credentials = token;
            console.log('session ', req.session.token.access_token);
            res.redirect('/details');
        }
        else{
            res.json({
                Error: 'Authorization error',
            });
        }
    });

})

app.get('/login', (req, res) => {
    let url = oauthClient.generateAuthUrl({
        access_type: 'offline',
        scope: config.google.scope
     }); 
    res.redirect(url)
})

app.get('/details', (req, res, next) => {
    console.log(req.session.token.access_token);
    plus.people.get({
        userId: 'me',
        auth: oauthClient
    }, (err, userInfo) => {
        if(err){
            console.log("Error while fetching user info");
        }
        else{
            res.json(userInfo);   
        }
    });
});

app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log("Server listening at " + port)
});
```

Comment: Call `next()` after '/auth/google/callback'. `res.redirect()` does not keep the request parameters.

Comment: Check incoming cookies, usually session id is stored in a cookie, cookies must not be passed from one call to the other.

Comment: `console.log(req.session.token.access_token);` --> this is not accessible because  there is no field as `token` in the beginning, it gets created after the user is authenticated. That is the reason why it gives me that error. Thank you guys! I appreciate your help.